# Spark executors crashing due to OOM when reading a small subset of a delta table on Google Cloud Storage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet, delta

I have a simple use case, I'm loading a delta table into Spark and I just want to view the first 1000 rows 
The table itself has 1B rows, and is of size ~29GB, split into 40 parts. 
The parquet is uncompressed and unpartitioned. 
The code is as follows

```
table_path = <gcs_bucket_path>
df = spark.read.format('delta').option('header', 'true').load(table_path)
df = df.limit(1000)
res = df.toJSON().collect()
```

I'm running executors with 1 core and 1GB of memory, which I thought would be more than enough as I'm reading a very small subset of the data, however, I'm getting OOM issues.

My question is why does this happen? Is Spark not smart enough to push down the limit and only read a small subset of the data in memory? Or read it in small batches to avoid OOM?